# How to expand d3 shape?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Assuming I have the following:

```
var vis = d3.select('svg')
    .attr({width: 400, height: 400});

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(50)
    .outerRadius(70)
    .startAngle(45 * (Math.PI/180)) //converting from degs to radians
    .endAngle(3) //just radians

var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(50)
    .outerRadius(30)
    .startAngle(180 * (Math.PI/180)) //converting from degs to radians
    .endAngle(5) //just radians

var position = [200,200];
```

How do I make it such that when mousing over a single arc, it causes both itself and the other arc to enlarge as well. When I say enlarge, I mean the innerRadius and outerRadius become bigger on mouseover and and shrink back to original size on mouse out.

I tried to cause a single arc to expand using:

```
arc.on("mouseover", function() {
   arc.innerRadius(40);
   arc.outerRadius(90);
});
```

Though it appears to have no effect at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to actually append your arc to the SVG:

```
var arcPath = vis.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc);
```

Doing this, you can see that the arc function simply generates an SVG path string, which you can set as the `d` property of a path. Therefore, on mouseover you need to update the `d` property of the path. For example you could do:

```
var arcHover = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(40)
    .outerRadius(90)
    .startAngle(45 * (Math.PI/180))
    .endAngle(3);

arcPath.on("mouseover", function(e) {
    arcPath.attr("d", arcHover);
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XaszF/